# Mocking fails in Django unittest of utils.py

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, python-3.x, mocking

I am trying to write a unittest for a function named `search_ldap()`, which searches an LDAP server given a particular username. Here is the function definition in `utils.py` (note: I'm using Python 3):

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection
def search_ldap(username):
    result = ()
    baseDN = "o=Universiteit van Tilburg,c=NL"
    searchFilter = '(uid={})'.format(username)
    attributes = ['givenName', 'cn', 'employeeNumber', 'mail']

    try:
        server = Server('ldap.example.com', use_ssl=True)
        conn = Connection(server, auto_bind=True)
        conn.search(baseDN, searchFilter, attributes=attributes)
        for a in attributes:
            result += (conn.response[0]['attributes'][a][0], )
    except Exception:
        raise LDAPError('Error in LDAP query')

    return result
```

Of course I don't want to actually connect to `ldap.example.com` during testing, so I've decided to use Python's [mock object library](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock.html) to mock the `Server()` and `Connection()` classes in my unittests. Here is the test code:

```
from unittest import mock
from django.test import TestCase
class LdapTest(TestCase):
    @mock.patch('ldap3.Server')
    @mock.patch('ldap3.Connection')
    def test_search_ldap(self, mockConnection, mockServer):
        from .utils import search_ldap
        search_ldap('username')
        self.assertTrue(mockServer.called)
        self.assertTrue(mockConnection.called)
```

This test simply asserts that the mocked Server and Connection objects are instantiated. However, thay don't, because when I run the tests with `./manage.py test` I receive the following error:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
F.
======================================================================
FAIL: test_search_ldap (uvt_user.tests.LdapTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/mock.py", line 1142, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "/home/jj/projects/autodidact/uvt_user/tests.py", line 28, in test_search_ldap
    self.assertTrue(mockServer.called)
AssertionError: False is not true

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.030s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Why are my tests failing? How can I successfully mock `ldap3`'s Server and Connection classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `patch()` it is important that you patch objects in the namespace where they are looked up. This is explained in the [Where to patch](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) section of the documentation. There is a fundamental difference between doing

```
from ldap3 import Server
server = Server()
```

and

```
import ldap3
server = ldap3.Server()
```

In the first case (also the case in the original question), the name "Server" belongs to the current module. In the second case, the name "Server" belongs to the ldap3 module where it is defined. The following Django unittest patches the correct "Server" and "Connection" names and should work as intended:

```
from unittest import mock
from django.test import TestCase
class LdapTest(TestCase):
    @mock.patch('appname.utils.Server')
    @mock.patch('appname.utils.Connection')
    def test_search_ldap(self, mockConnection, mockServer):
        from .utils import search_ldap
        search_ldap('username')
        self.assertTrue(mockServer.called)
        self.assertTrue(mockConnection.called)
```

Answer (score 0):

To mock class you should provide it's fake implementation with required methods. For example:

```
class FakeServer:
    def call():
        pass

class LdapTest(TestCase):
    @mock.patch('ldap3.Server', FakeServer)
    def test_search_ldap(self):
        <do you checks here>
```

Comment: Well, according to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock.html#quick-guide) you can also leave out a fake implementation and call `patch()` with a single argument. Still, I tried your solution and utils.py still imports the original `ldap3` module instead of the mocked one.